# Navigation bar not fully showing (blank space)?

Tags: html, css

[Picture for further explication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdbx.png)

So I've just been doing this with simple HTML and CSS since I'm kind of new. I copied the nav bar from w3schools (just for practice, obviously not for business) and I've encountered this problem. Here is my HTML and CSS, if you know the error please tell me and how I can fix it.

**HTML:**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
ul.topnav li.resize {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="resize">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Open the console on your browser. What errors does it give there?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wanted to fix the whitespace to the left of the navbar. Aside from the horrible organization of the CSS (see snippet for an example of better organization), you needed to add a `left: 0` to the `.topnav` to have it 0 (units) from the left of the screen.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato' , 'Arial' , 'Helvetica' , sans-serif;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
} 
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
ul.topnav li.resize {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="resize">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check here. this was you need?

```css
body {
font-family: 'Lato' , 'Arial' , 'Helvetica' , sans-serif;} ul.topnav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
width: 100%;} ul.topnav li {float: left;} ul.topnav li a {
display: inline-block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
line-height: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;}ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;} ul.topnav li.resize {display: none;}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="resize">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```